# What happens to the capacitance of a capacitor if we didn't allow a dielectric medium to touch the plates?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Usually we will encounter the condition that the dielectric touches both size of the metal plate and this will result in an increase of capacitance in the circuit just by timing the original capacitance by $K$. However, if dielectric does not touch either side of the plate or only touches one side of the plate, will it necessarily increase the circuit capacitance in the same way as the previous condition or will it acts as another capacitor which connects in series with the original two metal plate (result in a overall decrease in capacitance)?

Comment: If the dielectric doesn't touch one plate,  then the "dielectric" is now a combination of a material in series with air

Answer (score 0):

This effect is used by old-fashioned "compression trimmer capacitors", which fully compressed have their plates in contact with the dielectric (usually mica) and thus have maximum capacitance. The capacitance is adjusted by a screw that allows them to spring apart, so only one touches the dielectric. The larger the gap, the lower the capacitance.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question.